# Microsoft Graph Teams API not working when ResourceURI contains ending slash

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying out the beta API's for Microsoft Teams that exist within Microsoft Graph. I have noticed that my request always fails when requesting a token with resource uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/", but it works on other API endpoints like "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me".
If we change the resource uri to "https://graph.microsoft.com" the call does work for Teams releated API's.

Is this expected behaviour from the Graph? Is it related to being in beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. It should also work for "https://graph.microsoft.com/". Thank you for reporting this.  This should get fixed shortly.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you very much! This also explains why it is failing to load inside Power BI.